# Bot endpoint is giving 200 status but response body asks to sign in

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I am new to bot framework. I am trying to test bot which is deployed on the dev server.

I am following the following article:

https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/load-testing-a-bot/

I have got a token from the OAuth URL. Now I am trying to send a message to my deployed bot endpoint. I am getting 200 status but somehow body response gives me to text/Html content asks me to sign into your account.

Bots endpoint: [www.mydomain.azurwebsites.net/api/messages/v3](http://www.mydomain.azurwebsites.net/api/messages/v3)

I have passed the authorization token in the header. 
Authorization: bearer .
Can you please help me here?

Thanks

Comment: Just making it clear: You are asked to sign in again when you are trying to receive the token or when does it ask you to sign in again? Please try to give a sample of your code if possible.

Comment: I have got token successfully but asked to sign in when I am giving second call to post an activity.

Comment: Can you give the sample code please